# Test the RETVAL in the fish shell prompt?

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to convert my bashrc configuration into the fish shell config, and I have this part in the prompt:

```
function fish_prompt
  ....

  if [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]
    printf "✘"
  else
    printf "✓"
  end
  ....
end
```

This config leads to an error:

```
test: Missing argument at index 2
```

Can anybody explain to me, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RETVAL` is unset:

```
$ set -e RETVAL
$ if [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]; echo foo; end
test: Missing argument at index 2
$ set RETVAL 1
$ if [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]; echo foo; end
foo
```

If you want to suppress the error message, test for the existence of the variable. Also, use fish's builtin `test` instead of the external `[`

```
$ set -e RETVAL
$ if begin; set -q RETVAL; and test $RETVAL -ne 0; end; echo foo; else; echo bar; end
bar
$ set RETVAL 1
$ if begin; set -q RETVAL; and test $RETVAL -ne 0; end; echo foo; else; echo bar; end
foo
```

Actually, this is probably tidier:

```
if test -n "$RETVAL" -a "$RETVAL" -ne 0; echo foo; end
```

Comment: Note that `[` is a builtin in fish 2.1.0.